# How to reject or shutdown client connection in members until the member is fully initilialized?

Tags: hazelcast

I  have a member instance whose initialization takes up to a minute(configuration topic generation), even though the member is up and available on the network I don't want the clients to be able to connect to the server until server decides that it is ready to serve or reject incoming connections for a while.

I tried getting connected clients within the member code but Hazelcast 
returns Client interface reference which doesn't have a method like;

```
HazelcastInstance.shutdown(); or similar
```

but still it would be better if the member didn't even accept the incoming client connection in the first place until I want member to do so.

Comment: Do you consider Hazelcast Opensource or Enterprise? On Hazelcast Enterprise the SocketInterceptor might work, however tbh I never tried it myself. On OSS I don't think there's any way except fork and build it yourself, at least I wouldn't know how to do it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment I am using the open source version.due to the timeline of the current project and the complexity I really don't want to delve into hazelcast source code and make sure my additions are tested and working properly I wish they had had this feature in open source version

Comment: "hazelcast.initial.wait.seconds" Inital time in seconds to wait before node to start completely this is from hazelcast docs I wonder if means wait seconds until server accepts socket connections I can just give some delay to member until Suffield amount of time is provided for it to do its work

Comment: It is for members only, doesn't apply to clients (as far as I know)